# Is there a way to communicate between server and client in Python without opening up ports?

Tags: python, sockets

I was working on a *decentralized* python chat room. I was just wondering, if you don't open up a port, you can't receive messages. But, if you open up a port, you are vulnerable to getting hacked or something. So, is there a way to communicate with Python between a server and a client without opening up ports?

Comment: **"But, if you open up a port, you are vulnerable to getting hacked or something"**, well, I think that would be the least of your problems. Just use secure connections and that's all.

Comment: The vulnerability of open ports is not that they are ports, but that they are open. If you are open for any kind of communication, that leaves you vulnerable. You should focus on communicating securely, not on communicating without... erm... communicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of the client or the server should have an open port (typically, the server). As soon as a TCP connection is established (typically, by the client), a random (= chosen by the operating system) port will be used by the client to be reachable by the server.

Comment: By definition, an application listening for a connection is a server.